# Parameter Sweep in ADS by Keysight?

Tags: layout, s-parameters, ads

I am trying to create a Parameter Sweep in Momentum (ADS circuit layout simulator). Does anyone know how to do that? ADS offers options to create a parameter sweep during design but not during layout (atleast I don't know). And I am satisfied with my design, just not with the layout (because the s-parameters from EM simulations of the layout differ a lot from s parameters from design simulations).

Can anyone help me with that (Parameter sweep in layout EM simulations in ADS)?